# Pass state from one reducer to another in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers

I want to pass the state from my searchReducer to my movieReducer. The search takes in an input and saves the id of the movie(s), into state, I want to take that id value and pass it into the fetch for my movies, so that I can fetch each movie with the id and save the data into the movieReducer's state. How can I do this?

`actions.js`

```
// ------------------ SEARCH ------------------

export const searchMovie = text => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: SEARCH_MOVIE,
    payload: text
  })
}

export const fetchSearch = text => dispatch => {
  axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi?api_key=API_KEY&language=en-US&query=${text}&page=1&include_adult=false`)
  .then(response => dispatch({
    type: FETCH_SEARCH,
    payload: response.data.results.map(search => search.id)
  }))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

// ------------------ MOVIES ------------------

export const fetchMovie = text => dispatch => {
  axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${text}?api_key=API_KEY&append_to_response=videos,credits,recommendations,watch/providers`)
  .then(response => dispatch({
    type: SPECIFIC_MOVIE,
    payload: response.data.results
  }))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers  } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './App'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import favoritesReducer from './redux/favoritesReducer.js'
import moviesReducer from './redux/moviesReducer.js'
import showsReducer from './redux/showsReducer.js'
import userReducer from './redux/userReducer';
import searchReducer from './redux/searchReducer.js'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  favorties: favoritesReducer,
  movies: moviesReducer,
  shows: showsReducer,
  users: userReducer,
  search: searchReducer
})


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
let store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

export default
```

`searchReducer.js`

```
 const initialState = {
     text: '',
     movies: [],
     loading: false,
     movie: []
 }



const searchReducer = (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'SEARCH_MOVIE':
            return {
                ...state,
                text: payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case 'FETCH_SEARCH':
            return {
                ...state,
                movies: payload,
                loading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
} 

export default searchReducer
```

`movieReducer.js`

```
const initialState = {
    text: '',
    movie: []
}

const moviesReducer = (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
   switch (type) {
       case 'SPECIFIC_MOVIE':
           return {
               ...state,
               movie: payload
           };
       default:
           return state;
   }
} 

export default moviesReducer
```

`MoviePage.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMovie } from '../../actions/searchActions';

export class Movie extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovie(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
  render() {
    const { movie } = this.props;
    let movieInfo = (
      <div className="container">
            <img src={movie.Poster} className="thumbnail" alt="Poster" />
            <h2 className="mb-4">{movie.Title}</h2>
                <li>Genre:</li> {movie.Genre}
                <li>Released:</li> {movie.Released}
                <li>Rated:</li> {movie.Rated}
                <li>IMDB Rating:</li> {movie.imdbRating}
                <li>Director:</li> {movie.Director}
                <li>Writer:</li> {movie.Writer}
                <li>Actors:</li> {movie.Actors}
              <h3>About </h3>
              {movie.Plot}
    </div>
    );

    return <div>{}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  movie: state.movies.movie
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ fetchMovie })(Movie);
```

Comment: in Redux, there is no point in sending reducers, it is enough to connect correctly

Comment: I want to take that id value - Where?

Comment: The value I get from the search fetch, where I map and get the ids into the Search's state. I want to pass that state value into the movie fetch. That way I can fetch each movie and store the data into the movieReducer's state.

Comment: Where is the component code call the fetch? - it's place to change code

Comment: The fetch for the movie?

Comment: component whitch code calls fetch

Comment: In ```action.js```. I am running a fetch for searching movies, so when a user enters a movie name, it populates the array in ```searchReducer.js``` with the movie id. I want to then take that id from the ```searchReducer.js``` and use it to fetch for details about that specific movie. Which will be in ```movieReducer.js```

Comment: Well. I will ask differently. Where do you want to get this ID?

Comment: Show the component which use reducer (it is not in the above code)

Comment: Maybe @Filipe answer fits

Comment: If that doesn't help you, provide the code where you dispatch your fetchMovie action. You probably can extract what you need there with the useSelector method and then pass it to the action creator.

Comment: I'll try that answer, thanks. I also added the movie component into the original question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current state tree of your application using getState method inside of your action creator.

```
export const fetchMovie = text => (dispatch, getState) => {

  console.log(getState());   // you can see the info about your state tree here

  axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${text}?api_key=API_KEY&append_to_response=videos,credits,recommendations,watch/providers`)
  .then(response => dispatch({
    type: SPECIFIC_MOVIE,
    payload: response.data.results
  }))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```